# Can I install Ubuntu on a Samsung Galaxy Fit?

Tags: android, samsung, phone

I have a samsung galaxy fit GT-S5670L with Android 2.3.5 and I whant to install ubuntu on it with out modifying the android. It´s that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a tutorial for this already.

check this page :

[ubuntu on galaxy fit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1868377)

Comment: When I did it my phone coudnt boot android and i had to factory reset. But thanks